# What is the proper way to create an event handler inside a React function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-functional-component

I'm currently learning **react.js** and I just want to ask a question on how to properly create an *event handler function* inside a *function component*.

Pardon me since most examples in the official documentation are using **`class`** for this types of components.

I have an example code below that seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if this is the **correct way/best practice** when creating an event handler inside a function component, since every time the state changes I assume that the `handleClick` function is also recreated isn't it? This affects the performance every time we re-render right?

Say for example when I add more elements inside the `return` statement that can also trigger an event, and each event has a corresponding event handler that is also declared in that same function component, that might be an overhead for those extreme cases 'isn't that correct?

As far as I know this is not a problem on **class components** because they have a separate `render()` method so the event handler functions are not recreated, how do we do this in **function components**?

```js
function Toggle (props) {
  const [isToggleOn, setToggle] = React.useState(false)

  function handleClick (e) {
    setToggle(() => !isToggleOn)
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      {isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: In this instance you will want the function to be recreated on each render. Otherwise `isToggleOn` won't be correct. Or use the answer Vencovsky wrote.

Comment: @evolutionxbox or just use the previous state. There's no need to use `isToggleOn` there.

Comment: @Vencovsky yep, that's why I recommended your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the `handleClick` function to be recreated on each render, you should use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook.

```
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
  setToggle((previousState) => !previousState)
}, [])
```

This way, `handleClick` is created only at the initial render because the `useCallback`'s dependency array is empty.

You might also notice that I removed the usage of `isToggleOn` and instead use the previous state in the `setToggle` so your function don't need to depend on `isToggleOn`.